# Nodejs express mongo Find query sending multiple result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a simple code to find data by object id like this

```
router.get(`/treeDetails/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    const tree = await Tree.find({ treeID: req.params.id })

    if (!tree) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false });
    }
    // console.log(tree[0].relatives.filter(e => e.parentRelative));
    tree[0].relatives = tree[0].relatives.filter(e => e.parentRelative == null);
    res.send({ success: true, data: tree[0] });
});
```

Its is sending multiple data which treeID is not even same you can see also in postman.

[image]

But if I use other value _id instead of treeID (Both have the same ids) then its works fine

Just replace this line

```
const tree = await Tree.find({ _id: req.params.id })
```

Need to know why its not working with treeID event both have same value

Comment: in your if statement you need an `return` to stop the function for executing further: `return res.status(500).json({ success: false });`

Answer (score 0):

**You Can try this**

```
const tree = await Tree.findById(req.params.id)
```